# Detect dominant intensity area in an image using x-,y- gradients

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect the dominant intensity area from an image where there is a foreground object. I can detect the edges of the object with the sobel operator using x and y gradients. But, I am having difficulty in detecting the dominant area of the image. I need the pixel values of the dominant intensity area in the image.

For example, in Image 1, the background (the gray part) has dominant area and in Image 2, the object (the black part) has dominant area. I would like to get the pixel values of the dominant area in Image 1 and 2.

Image 1:[image]
Image 2:[image]

I have done the edge detection as follow:

```
Mat mat2gray(const cv::Mat& src)
    {
    Mat dst;
    normalize(src, dst, 0.0, 255.0, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U);

    return dst;
    }



int main(void)
    {
    Mat img = imread("Image.png", -1);

    Mat cvsx,cvsy;
    Sobel(img, cvsx, CV_32F, 1, 0);
    Sobel(img, cvsy, CV_32F, 0, 1);

    imshow("x", mat2gray(cvsx));
    imshow("y", mat2gray(cvsy));

    Mat mag;
    magnitude(cvsx, cvsy, mag);
    imshow("magnitude", mat2gray(mag));


    waitKey();
    return 0;
    }
```

I have a feeling that it might be possible with the gradient magnitude and gradient direction, but I couldn't quite figure it out. I would really appreciate any help regarding obtaining the dominant intensity area of image.

**Update:** here is an example image with 3 intensity level. This is a depth image obtained from depth camera.

Image 3:[image]

Comment: Reduce to two colours, then greyscale and normalize the image so it is pure black and white. Check the mean. If the mean is <0.5 the black area is dominant, else white.

Comment: *I would like to get the pixel values of the dominant are*, what do you mean by pixel values ?

Comment: @ZdaR : the intensity values of the pixels inside the dominant area of the image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: thanks for your suggestion. I will try that out, however, is there a way to do such using sobel operators?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I am talking about gradient based solution, because I only showed a simplified example in those images. It might occur that there are more than 1 object in the image with different intensity values. In that case, I suppose detecting the edges and then finding out the dominant area would be better. Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Maybe show more representative images...

Comment: The question is quite vague. If there are multiple objects and you don't know their number nor their color, you could look at color histograms and clustering methods. I don't think gradients are a good way of doing this because, basically, they will tell you about intensity changes ... But as Mark said, show us some representative images !

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Please find another representative image in the 'Update' section of my question. Here, there are 3 intensities: while, gray and dark gray. About your previous response, could you please elaborate about "Reduce to two colors": how should I reduce the previous simplified images to 2 colors. An example code would be much helpful.

Comment: @Ben:  Please find another representative image in the 'Update' section of my question. Here, there are 3 intensities: while, gray and dark gray. I am trying to reduce the ghosting artifact of image sequence. Here the object is moving from one frame to another.

Comment: So your image appears to comprise a dark grey background and an object comprising whiteish and blackish tones? Presumably you could take all pixels within N% of dark grey and call them background and all very light and very dark pixels and call them the object. Then your task is not too hard.